# jquery autocomplete hides itself on window blur, disable this

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

jquery's autocomplete is hiding itself on window blur, how to prevent this?

Can't find the answer on the Internet.

Sounds simple but with the following code to determine window focus and blur I get display none for all autocomplete that were opened right before going into blur, seems window blur is the trigger for autocomplete to hide:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).focus(function() {

    });

    $(window).blur(function() {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").each(function(){alert($(this).css("display"));});
    });


});
```

I wanted to set variables for all autocomplete that had a display other than none and then on focus display these, but on blur I get display none for all ".ui-autocomplete"

Comment: fill in the blanks ....??no we wont its not an exam for us ... just try and then if you have got any problem we would love to help

Comment: Sounds like the autocomplete hides when it gets blurred. Hooking into the window blur event won't help, it's higher up the propagation path. You need to removed the blur handler from the autocomplete, or add a blur handler lower down the path and stop propagation there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the autocomplete's `blur` event handler like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: ['cat','rabbit','donkey']
    }).off('blur').on('blur', function() {
        if(document.hasFocus()) {
            $('ul.ui-autocomplete').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Using the `hasFocus()` function you can check the focus of the current window and determine wether to close the options or not

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pNmnW/)

Comment: Only problem seems to be first is triggered the blur event over the autocomplete and then over the window, so hasFocus() won't work to check whether the document has lost focus.

Comment: Works well by adding a timeout though, but it sure is hacky and unreliable. A timeout with 0 as the timer so it looks good.. Do you see anyway of targeting all autocomplete in the document and add the off handler for the blur to all these at once?

Comment: As the autocomplete widget will assign a class to the autocomplete `input`, you could try selecting them all with `$('.ui-autocomplete-input')`